# как запустить параллельную работу нескольких ботов на сервере при помощи systemd

Tags: python, systemd

При помощи systemd запустил работу бота телеграмм.

В файле bot.service путь для запуска ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/bot/main.py

Как сюда добавить еще одного бота? Приписать еще одну команду типа ExecStart = ? или нужно по другому сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо создать еще один файл systemd.service прописать в нем новый путь для запуска бота, далее прописать по очереди две команды systemctl daemon-reload и systemctl enable #имя бота.

Ну и запустить его systemctl start #имя бота